# Yellow triangle over Frameworks\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.0

I'm using VS2019 Pro v16.3.5. I have installed the .Net Core 3.0 SDK.

I have an Azure Durable Functions C# project that makes use of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions v3.0.0.0

This assembly is contained within the shared framework Microsoft.AspNetCore.App. So, I've added a reference to this from my csproj file, as seen below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3-preview</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

Trouble is VS seems to have difficulty resolving this. In Solution Explorer, for my project, I get a yellow triangle over Dependencies\Frameworks\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App:

[image: frameworks pic]

I also get the following compilation error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.

Comment: As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#remove-obsolete-package-references) you should remove obsolete references. You can remove the line: `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`

Comment: @RuardvanElburg thanks for that - would you like to provide as an answer so I can mark as correct

Comment: I was working on the answer, but now I noticed that according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference) Microsoft.NET.Sdk should add an explicit FrameworkReference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App. So I wonder if the issue is in fact a conflict which is resolved by removing the framework reference, even though it should be referenced, according to documentation.

Comment: Hmm good point!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also had this issue after migrating to VS2019/netcore3.0

During migration I had to add a FrameworkReference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App, just like Ruard pointed out.

In my case the **solution** was to :

1. close the solution
2. delete all bin/obj folder
3. (most important) delete the .vs folder.

Hope this will solve your problem as well.